# sql error Only one expression

Tags: sql

My query is as follows, and contains a subquery within it:

```
@catid int

AS
    Select Top(1)
    ID,
    Title,
    Description,
    NewsType,
    CreateTime,
    ISNULL(( ImageURL2 ),'no-pic') As [News-Photo],
    ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(50),ImageTime),'no-date') As [News-Date],
    (select top(5) id,title From News ) as [SpLinks]
    From News 
    Where (NewsType = @catid) and (AllowShow = 'True')
    order by CreateTime Desc
```

The error I am receiving is Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

A subquery in a column place can only return one value.

If you're looking for multiple rows, change your subquery:

```
...
(select top(5) id,title From News ) as [SpLinks]
From News 
...
```

To a join:

```
...
,      SpLinks.id
,      SpLinks.title
from   News 
cross join   
       (
       select  top(5) id
       ,       title 
       from    News 
       ) as SpLinks
...
```

Comment: i change to :

@catid int

AS
 Select Top(1)
 ID,
 Title,
 Description,
 NewsType,
 CreateTime,
 ISNULL(( ImageURL2 ),'no-pic') As [News-Photo],
 ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(50),ImageTime),'no-date') As [News-Date]
    From News cross join   
       (
       select  top(5) id,title 
       from    News 
       ) as SpLinks
 Where (NewsType = @catid) and (AllowShow = 'True')
 order by CreateTime Desc


but get this error :

ambiguous column name 'ID'
ambiguous column name 'Title'

Comment: You'd have to prefix `ID`, like `News.ID` or `SpLinks.ID`.